# Is It Possible To Create My Own Shortcode

Tags: module, magento-1, core, template-directive

I'm building a module. I want to be able to use a shortcode *(template directive)* in my CMS static blocks, such as the following:

```
{{store url=""}}
```

I want to call my own module's frontpage blocks using this method. Is this even possible? Google has turned up nothing about writing my own.

Comment: See also http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/63421/3326

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to override this model: <strike>`Mage_Cms_Model_Template_Filter`</strike> `Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter` and add a method for your own shortcode. 
Let's assume your short code is called 'custom', you need to add a method called `customDirective($construction)` that handles your shrotcode.
To get an idea on how that method should look like, take a look at `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::storeDirective()`. This method handles the `store` shortcode.

To get the parameters passed to the short code use this:

```
$params = $this->_getIncludeParameters($construction[2]);
```

After processing them you need to return a string value that will replace the `{{custom ...}}` placeholder.

**[Edit]**
I realized my mistake. The `Widget` module changes the template processor. Here is the piece of code that worked for me.
file `app/etc/modules/Easylife_Widget.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Widget>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Widget />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Widget>
    </modules>
</config>
```

file `app/code/local/Easylife/Widget/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Widget>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Widget>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <widget>
                <rewrite>
                    <template_filter>Easylife_Widget_Model_Template_Filter</template_filter>
                </rewrite>
            </widget>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

file `app/code/local/Easylife/Widget/Model/Template/Filter.php`

```
<?php

class Easylife_Cms_Model_Template_Filter extends Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter{
    public function customDirective($construction){
        $params = $this->_getIncludeParameters($construction[2]); 
        return print_r($params, 1);
    }
}
```

Clear the cache.
Now when I enter `{{custom}}` in the page content I get back `Array()`.
If I enter `{{custom var1="6"}}` I get `Array ( [var1] => 6 )`.

Comment: You say override this model Marius, is there a way to `extend` it rather? I assume I need to reference my new model in the config.xml file?

Comment: I've edited the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: I've edited the answer again. I overlooked something the first time.

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly now. Can I "mark as answer" twice? Thanks so much Marius.

Answer (score 4):

Given the popularity of this question, thought I'd add this; there's (obviously) a similar way to mimic this functionality. If the block type of `core/template` is used, we can access the data array using `getData()`.

For example, if we create a block in CMS similar to the following:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="a_sweet_title" bimg="my_profile_pic.jpg"
    bwidth="250" bheight="500" template="mymodule/my_template_file.phtml"}}
```

Then we can access that data in the `phtml` file using `getData()`:

```
$imgSrc = $this->getData('bimg');
$blockWidth = $this->getData('bwidth');
$blockHeight = $this->getData('bheight');
```

Or, better yet, even retrieve a record/collection using a block parameter:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodule')->load($theId);
```

Armed with that knowledge, maybe ask yourself; '*Do I really need a custom shortcode*'? Hope it helps.