# Add new custom CMS template directive {{cdnmedia}}

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, cms, media, cdn

I want to add a new CMS directive to render CDN media URL's just like the media directive:

```
{{media url="wysiwyg/image.jpg"}}
```

Will result in `http://www.example.com/media/wysiwyg/image.jpg`

Now I have some specific images that will be hosted on a separate CDN. I want to be able to render URL's to those images from CMS pages/blocks:

```
{{cdnmedia url="images/picture.jpg"}}
```

This should result in `http://cdn.example.com/images/picture.jpg` where the CDN base URL would be configurable.

I already have a helper that can take `"images/picture.jpg"` as input and will return a full CDN URL (based on configured secure and unsecure CDN bas URL's).

How can I add this into the CMS rendering?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I've done it right now.

### Overriding CMS template filter

The CMS Helper contains two methods called `getPageTemplateProcessor()` and `getBlockTemplateProcessor()` which will do `Mage::getModel(...)` with input of the configured model name from the config respectively at `global/cms/page/tempate_filter` and `global/cms/block/tempate_filter`.

So add this to your module's `config.xml` to replace the original values of `widget/template_filter` (set in `app/code/core/Mage/Widget/etc/config.xml`):

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <global>
        <models>
            <mymodule_cdn>
                <class>MyModule_Cdn_Model</class>
            </mymodule_cdn>
        </models>
        <cms>
            <page>
                <tempate_filter>mymodule_cdn/template_filter</tempate_filter>
            </page>
            <block>
                <tempate_filter>mymodule_cdn/template_filter</tempate_filter>
            </block>
        </cms>
    </global>
</config>
```

***Sidenotes:***

1. *notice the node name `<tempate_filter>` is missing the 'l' in 'template' which is a typo in Magento core*
2. *This is a form of rewrite. The last loaded module will do this rewrite effectively, therefore also it would be good practice to make your module `<depends>` on `<Mage_Widget />`*

### Custom template filter model with 'cdnmedia' directive

And the model:

```
class MyModule_Cdn_Model_Template_Filter extends Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter
{
    /**
     * CDN media URL filter
     *
     * @param array $construction
     * @return string
     */
    public function cdnmediaDirective($construction)
    {
        $params = $this->_getIncludeParameters($construction[2]);

        if (!isset($params['url']) || '' == trim($params['url'])) {
            return '';
        }

        $secure = null;
        if (isset($params['secure'])) {
            $secure = in_array($params['secure'], array('1', 'true', 'on', 'yes'));
        }

        return Mage::helper('mymodule_cdn')->getUrl($params['url'], $secure);
    }
}
```

### Rendering the actual URL

The question is how to add the directive, not the actual URL creation, but for completeness, here's the 'mymodule_cdn' helper `getUrl()` method:

```
/**
 * Get CDN URL for path
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @param null|boolean $secure
 * @return string
 */
public function getUrl($path = '', $secure = null)
{
    if ($secure === null) {
        $secure = intval(Mage::getStoreConfig('mymodule_cdn/default/is_secure')) > 0;
    }
    return rtrim(($secure === true
            ? Mage::getStoreConfig('mymodule_cdn/secure/base_url')
            : Mage::getStoreConfig('mymodule_cdn/unsecure/base_url')
        ), '/')
        . '/' . ltrim($path, '/');
}
```

### Usages

You can use the `{{cdnmedia}}` directive now in your CMS pages and static blocks:

```
<img src="{{cdnmedia url="images/picture.jpg" secure="true"}}" />
<!-- will render: -->
<img src="https://cdn.example.com/images/picture.jpg" />
```

And because of the use of a helper building the actual URL, you can use this in phtml templates:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('mymodule_cdn')->getUrl('images/picture.jpg', true); ?>" />
<?php /* will render: */ ?>
<img src="https://cdn.example.com/images/picture.jpg" />
```

#### Reference

Used this article as reference: http://de.nr-apps.com/blog/2013/01/16/magento-store-url-template-directive/

Comment: Why you rewrite the filter in this way, instead of using `<rewrite>` node?

Comment: Where should a do a rewrite? I want to _add_ a template directive, not change one. And also I always learned rewrites are bad, because they will inevitably lead to rewrite conflicts (when other exts/mods/code also needs to rewrite the same)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I misunderstood _The is a form of rewrite._

Comment: Ah, I get it now. I guess this was an early form of DI already :P

Comment: Maybe, just maybe in some cases you won't need to create new directive. You can try to use modifier! http://aleron75.com/2017/01/28/modifiers-in-magento-e-mail-templates/

Answer (score 4):

You can find code in below url, how you can define your custom `directives` to use in `Magento CMS` pages & `Static Block`.

http://dltr.org/blog/magento/567/Magento-add-your-own-CMS-Directive-to-include-your-custom-template-tag

I have used this method before for me & its worked well for me.

Comment: Aha, very nice. I'm going to try this right away

Comment: I've put my code in a separate answer. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction!