# How to create a custom Filter directive (e.g. for emails)?

Tags: magento-2.1, email-templates

Depending on a custom order's attribute, we would like to slightly adapt the emails for the new order confirmations.

Therefor, we try to implement a new equals directive in `Magento\Framework\Filter\Template` (we extend this class in a custom module, of course). This directive should take two parameters and evaluate whether these values are equal. Magento's build in `if` directive only checks, if the given parameter is not equal an empty string.

For example:

```
{{equals value1 value2}}The two parameters are equal.{{else}}The two parameters are NOT equal.{{/equals}}
```

We added the following constant to our custom `Template.php`:

```
const CONSTRUCTION_EQUALS_PATTERN = '/{{equals\s*(.*?)}}(.*?)({{else}}(.*?))?{{\\/equals\s*}}/si';
```

The value of this constant is the same as the value of the `CONSTRUCTION_IF_PATTERN` constant, except we replaced both `if` with `equals`.

Furthermore, we override the `filter($value)` function of the original `Template` and teach this function to execute a new callback named `equalsDirective`, if one of the given `values` matches to above defined pattern.

```
foreach ([
  self::CONSTRUCTION_DEPEND_PATTERN => 'dependDirective',
  self::CONSTRUCTION_IF_PATTERN => 'ifDirective',
  self::CONSTRUCTION_TEMPLATE_PATTERN => 'templateDirective',
  self::CONSTRUCTION_EQUALS_PATTERN => 'equalsDirective' // this is interesting line
] as $pattern => $directive)
```

The function `equalsDirective` just should write a debug message, when it's got called.

Additionally, we adapt the template for the new orders confirmation emails (`Magento\Sales\view\email\order_new.html`) by adding the following beneath the greeting:

```
{{equals order.checkout_type request}}This is a request.{{else}}This is an order.{{/equals}}
```

The problem is, the `equalsDirective` function never gets called. The given values of the `filter` function do not contain the above equals directive. Thus, a pattern -- as defined above -- never is found.

We also verified that `{{var order.checkout_type}}` returns the correct value. Surprisingly, this is not part of the given values of the `filter` function, as well. But its value is correctly rendered in the email that we received.

Has someone an idea what we missed? Do we have to declare the directives that are parsed from the email templates somewhere else?

We appreciate any help :)

FYI: Couple of years ago we did the same in Magento 1 and it was working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like in 2.3.4 this logic was modified and now you can use di.xml to inject your directives by passing it into the `directiveProcessors` property of the constructor, see gitlab [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.4/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/Template.php#L120).

Taken from Magento's [original](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email-migration.html#create-a-custom-directive) article for v2.3.4

> Create a class that implements Magento\Framework\Filter\SimpleDirective\ProcessorInterface:

```
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace GadgetCorp\CustomEmailDirective\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Filter\SimpleDirective\ProcessorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
/**
* Calculates the lifetime spend of all customers
*/
class LifetimeSpendDirective implements ProcessorInterface
{
 /**
 * @var PriceCurrencyInterface
 */
 private $priceCurrency;

 /**
 * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
 */
 public function __construct(PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency)
 {
     $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
 }

 /**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
 public function getName(): string
 {
     return 'lifetime_spend';
 }

 /**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
 public function process($value, array $parameters, ?string $html): string
 {
     $shouldBold = !empty($parameters['should_bold']);
     $amount = $this->priceCurrency->getCurrencySymbol() . $this->calculateLifetimeSpend();
     return ($shouldBold ? '<strong>' . $amount . '</strong>' : $amount);
 }

 /**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
 public function getDefaultFilters(): ?array
 {
     // Make sure newlines are converted to <br /> tags by default
     return ['nl2br'];
 }

 /**
 * Calculate the total amount of money spent by all customers for all time
 *
 * @return float
 */
 private function calculateLifetimeSpend(): float
 {
     // Add code here to calculate the lifetime spend
     return 123.45;
 }
```

}

> Add the new directive to the pool by adding this block to di.xml.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <type name="Magento\Framework\Filter\SimpleDirective\ProcessorPool">
 <arguments>
     <argument name="processors" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="lifetime_spend" xsi:type="object">GadgetCorp\CustomEmailDirective\Model\LifetimeSpendDirective</item>
     </argument>
 </arguments>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what we found out after some more hours of research. Probably, it is not best practice, but it does work for now. We would be glad, if someone would give us hints in order to improve this solution.

It is not sufficient to only extend the `Magento\Framework\Filter\Template` and override the `filter()` function.
In the `Magento_Email` module you can find the `Model\Template\Filter` which is used for the email template processing.
This class extends the `Magento\Framework\Filter\Template` and overrides its `filter()` function, too. Inside this `filter()` function the parent function is called, which is not the function of our `Template` class but the one of Magento's original `Template` class (`Magento\Framework\Filter\Template`);

Thus, you have to override the `Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter` class, as well.
Copy the whole `Filter` class to your custom module and make it extend your -- previously mentioned -- `Template` class that extends the `Magento\Framework\Filter\Template`.

Now, we can use the above declared `equals` directive inside the email templates and it is working fine.

Nevertheless, we discovered the following drawbacks:

- We had to copy the whole `Filter` class. Otherwise we need multiple inheritance from `Magento\Framework\Filter\Template` and `Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter`.
- The `Filter` class that we copied uses the `Magento\Email\Model\Template\Css\Processor` class. This class is not in the module's API. Thus, we copied this class to our custom module, as well.

As mentioned in the first paragraph, we would appreciate any hints that help us to improve this solution.