# Custom FIlter for Email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates

As per the Magento documentation, we can create custom directive like `{{var}} {{if}} {{depends}}`
using this documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email-migration.html#abstraction-example.

We are using filters like `nl2br`, `escape`, `raw` So, Is it possible to extend the filters also? for eg. strtoupper to convert all things In upper case.

**UPDATE**

> etc/di.xml

```
 <type name="Magento\Framework\Filter\DirectiveProcessor\Filter\FilterPool">
     <arguments>
         <argument name="filters" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="capitalize" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\CapitalizeWord</item>
         </argument>
     </arguments>
 </type>
```

> CapitalizeWord.php

```
 <?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
 use Magento\Framework\Filter\DirectiveProcessor\FilterInterface; 
 class CapitalizeWord implements FilterInterface
 {
     public function getName(): string
     {
         return 'capitalize';
     }
     /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
     public function filterValue($value, array $params): string
     {
        return ucwords($value);

     }
 }
```

Comment: What you are looking for is a custom email filter directive https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/303561/70343

Comment: No I am looking for filter. There is a `filterPool` same as  `ProcessorPool` but when email template render `filterPool` not working

Comment: This you mean https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/Filter/EscapeFilter.php?

Comment: yes something like this so I can create my own class and return result like `strtoupper($value)`

Answer (score 0):

You write something similar to my comment

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/Filter/EscapeFilter.php

It would be StrtoupperFilter.php for example

```php
use Vendor\Extension\Filter\DirectiveProcessor\Filter;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\Filter\DirectiveProcessor\FilterInterface;

/**
 * StrtoupperInput
 */
class StrtoupperFilter implements FilterInterface {
```

Where

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function getName(): string
{
    return 'strtoupper';
}
```

Adapt the following to you needs

```
public function filterValue(string $value, array $params): string
```

And then add di XML. Structure would look a bit like this...

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/e42ed8dcf89ce65d7ba4af489fc6e6cd764e161b/app/code/Magento/Email/etc/di.xml#L85-L92

```
Vendor/Extension/etc/di.xml
```

```
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Filter\DirectiveProcessor\Filter\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="strtoupper" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Extension\Filter\DirectiveProcessor\Filter\StrtoupperFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

The FilterPool mechanisnm will pick it up and add it to the pool

Then should be the case of

```
{{var param|strtoupper}}
```

in template

Comment: I have tried this but this filter pool not call when email template is render. May be because  this file will call when filter apply for the template https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/e42ed8dcf89ce65d7ba4af489fc6e6cd764e161b/app/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template/Filter.php

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I have updated my question with Code.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be any resolution - any resolution will be much appreciated.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/208338)